# Подключение к удаленной бд MySQL в Android

Tags: android, mysql

Необходимо подключиться к внешней БД MySQL в Android приложении, которое бы использовало ресурсы готового сервиса, но **без** API.
Знаю, что это нехорошо, но просто стоит такая задача.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вкрутить MySQL-клиент в Android-приложение, пусть это и нехорошо. В чём именно проблема?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того что бы подключится к БД Вам потребуется:

1.**Подключить** к проекту `JDBC Driver` для `MySQL`. Если пользуетесь `AS` то в зависимостях укажите следующую строку:

```
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6'
```

2.Перед первым обращением к базе необходимо **зарегистрировать** драйвер:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

Строка `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` зависит от подключенного драйвера.

3.Получаем **соединение** с базой так:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
```

Естественно заменяем hostname, port, dbname, username и password на свои.

**PS**: и да, не забываем производить соединение и всяческие манипуляции с базой **не в UI потоке**. Про разрешения в манифесте так же забывать не стоит.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: @NadezhdaChezhegova и да, хотелось бы так же заметить, что не все хостинги бесплатно предоставляют возможность прямого подключения к базе...эт я так, если вдруг это ваш случай, что бы сэкономить время)

Comment: в каком формате данные получает это интерфейс?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/index.html  - тут можете ознакомиться с основными моментами работы с jdbc