# Как подключиться и вывести данные из базы MySQL в Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio

Создаю приложение в Android Studio, мне необходимо взять данные из таблицы базы MySQL и вывести их в Android Studio. Как подключиться к базе MySQL и вывести данные?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подключение к удаленной бд MySQL в Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507324/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b4-mysql-%d0%b2-android)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio не поддерживает прямое подключение к БД MySQL!
Для создания, получения, изменения или удаления используется API, средствами для получения данных используется JSON или XML.